# problem in fetching data from api while using react kanban package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack, kanban

while fetching data locally it works but while fetching data from the api it doesnot displays . `

```
       <Board
            initialBoard={content}
            renderColumnHeader={({ name, badge }) => (
              <RenderCardTitle name={name} badge={badge} />
            )}
            renderCard={(data, { dragging }) => (
              <CardTaskBox data={data} dragging={dragging} content={content}  >
                {data}
              </CardTaskBox>
            )}
            onNewCardConfirm={draftCard => ({
              id: new Date().getTime(),
              ...draftCard,
            })}
            onCardDragEnd = {onCardMove}
          />
```

`
tried many times but i am not getting the point why this issue is arising??

this completely works when passing local data but not works white passing the data coming from api

Comment: Can you edit it in some way that make it reproducable?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: sorry @AmirhosseinSefati ??

Comment: @Geshode , no i am not getting any error but it is not displaying anything , but when passing data locally in {content} is is displaying data properly

Comment: Please provide code where you assign value to content variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.